# Define Database connection for two different datasets using variables in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a requirement of connecting to two different datasets using a variable which compares these datasets. I'm using two different table input steps where the database connection names, hostnames are hard coded. 
Instead of using hardcoded I want to use a variable which defines these connections and should be able to connect to them[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define variables in the kettle.properties file, located in the .kettle directory. Then you can use these variables in your database connection settings.

You can also define variables in your own .properties files and read them in using the Set Variables job entry.

set the variables like:

```
db_name.host=localhost
db_name.db=databasename
db_name.user=username
```

Then access those variables in your job/transformation by using the format `${db_name.host}` etc.

Comment: I've tried defining the variables with name ${DB_NAME} = mybd, ${DB_Host} = xyz, and ${user} = creator in kettle.properties file. But, in my view I'm using 5 different datasoures are beinjg used. And, I'm comparing two datasets in each transformation. So, I'm unable to define variable value for the target dataset since, I've already defined the default value for my source dataset in kettle.properties file. Please help me on this

Comment: Just to clarify, the `${VARIABLE}` notation should be used to call the variable in the job/transformation. In kettle.properites, the variable should be defined simply as `VARIABLE=variable_value`.

Also, you can define more than one set of connection details in the kettle.properties. You can define as many connections as you want like:
```
db_firstdatabase.host=localhost
db_firstdatabase.db=databasename
db_firstdatabase.user=username

db_seconddatabase.host=localhost
db_seconddatabase.db=databasename
db_seconddatabase.user=username
```

Please clarify if this isn't what you meant.

Comment: Agree to your answer that we can specify as many database connections using variables in a transformation/job by editing kettle.properties file. But, my question was is there any way that we can use only one variable for database connection, one for hostname, and one for user instead of using two different variables database connection, two for host connection and two for user connection. Since, I'm comparing two different data sets in a transformation and I want to use only one for db connection, one for user and one host instead of using two variables each.That's what my concern was

Comment: Are the connection details (host, db name, user, etc) the same between these two different Table Input steps? If they are, then yes. You can absolutely use the same variables in both Table Input steps.

Comment: @eicherjec the two data-sources are different.

Answer (score 0):

Use JNDI to set up all your connection parameters:

(1) edit the file: `data-integration/simple-jndi/jdbc.properties`, and add your DB connection strings, for example:

```
db1/type=javax.sql.DataSource
db1/driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db1/url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3305/mydb
db1/user=user1
db1/password=password1 
db2/type=javax.sql.DataSource
db2/driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db2/url=jdbc:mysql://mydbserver:3306/mydb
db2/user=user2
db2/password=password2
```

Here we created two JNDI name `db1` and `db2` which we can use in PDI jobs/transformations.

(2) In your PDI job/transformation, add a parameter, i.e. `mydb`, through the menu 'Edit' -> `Settings...` -> `Parameters` Tab. You can add more such DB parameters if more than one is used.

(3) In the `Table Input` step, click `Edit...` or `New..` button and in the coming dialog, switch the item in `Access:` box to `JNDI` and then add the ${mydb} in the `JNDI name` at the upper-right corner. you can also use plain text `db1` and `db2` which we defined in (1) to identify the DB connection.

Using JNDI to manage DB connections, we were able to switch between staging and production DBs simply by using the parameters. You can do the similar to `PRD`.